# form fields not getting posted to php file when using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an HTML file that has a form with two fields. These fields' value should be posted to a PHP and this PHP should be fetched from the HTML using JQuery. This is what I implemented.

My HTML file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("button").click(function(){
                $("#first").load("result_jquery.php");
            });
        });     

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" id="myForm">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
        Number: <input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
        <button>submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my **result_jquery.php**

```
<?php
$n = $_POST["name"];
echo "hello ".$n;
?>
```

When I click the submit button, the hello is getting printed. But the name is not getting printed. Can you please help me with this. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `<input type='submit'/> instead of button?  It doesn't look like it is actually sending the POST request.

Comment: You load the page, but never post any information to it in your Jquery.  Look in to the [JQuery `$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method. ^^

Comment: yes I tried the submit. Its still not working. Actually I observed that even by removing the <form> tag, the result is the same.

Comment: I added the following. But it didnt work.  `<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
   $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
 data : $(this).serialize(),
cache: false, url: "result_jquery.php", }); $("#first").load("result_jquery.php"); });
 }); 
</script>

Comment: i am sorry about the code indentation. i dont know why the newlines were not printed. I am new to stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the use of the button element is the worry and the code that i will put now it is working properly as you need so try this and tell me the result :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#button").click(function(){
            var n = $('[name="namee"]').val();
            var nb = $('[name="number"]').val();
            $("#first").load("result_jquery.php",{'namee':n,'number':nb},function(data){});
        });
    });     

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" id="myForm">
            Name: <input type="text" name="namee"/><br/>
            Number: <input type="text" name="number"/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="button" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great ! And my really thanks is that my solution work perfectly and as you need :) If you need any additional help just i am here :)

Answer (score 1):

copy  this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            data : "name="+$( '#name' ).val(),
            url: "result_jquery.php", 
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#first').html(msg);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

change this in form

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br/>
    Number: <input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="send" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I did that. But when I click the submit button, nothing is happening other than refresh and the field values are dissappearing( because of the refresh)

Comment: change <button id="send">submit</button> to <input type="button" id="send" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation on `load`:

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the
>   method can be quite simple:

You are performing a HTTP GET with that method, and not a POST.

My suggestion would be if you want to send an AJAX request to your server with information in it, get used to using the long form jQuery AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    data: 'url=encoded&query=string&of=data&or=object',
    url: 'path/to/server/script.php',
    success: function( output ) {
        // Handle response here
    }
});
```

For more info, see jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: They are preforming a `GET`, but they also don't do anything with the form data in that method, so changing the PHP to `$_GET` won't help at all.

Comment: I added the following. But it didnt work.  
`<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("button").click(function(){
                   $.ajax({   
                            type: "POST",
//                            data : $(this).serialize(),
                            data : "name",
                            cache: false,  
                            url: "result_jquery.php",   
                            });   
                    $("#first").load("result_jquery.php");
                });
            });     
            
        </script> `

Comment: i am sorry about the code indentation. i dont know why the newlines were not printed. I am new to stack overflow

Comment: When i am using <form> tag, the php file is not getting loaded when I called with jquery. When I delete the <form> tag, its getting loaded. But the form fields are not getting passed.

Comment: Your 'data' needs to be either a JSON object with the values pulled from your form elements or a URL Encoded query string (also with the data that you want to POST to the server)

Answer (score 0):

just try that and tell me the result :)

```
var n = $('[name="name"]').val();
var nb = $('[name="number"]').val();
$('#error').load("result_jquery.php", {'name':n,'number':nb},function(data){});
```

Note try to change the element name for the name field from "name" to "namee" and apply changes as needed look like this :

```
var n = $('[name="namee"]').val();
var nb = $('[name="number"]').val();
$('#error').load("result_jquery.php", {'namee':n,'number':nb},function(data){});
```

and the result_jquery.php file :

```
<?php
$n = $_POST["name"];
echo "hello ".$n;
?>
```

Comment: When i am using <form> tag, the php file is not getting loaded when I call with jquery. When I delete the <form> tag, its getting loaded. But the form fields are not getting passed. Can the <form> tage be used when using jquery?