# Sending data with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have more than one problem. First one:

How can I send more than one data including JS functions:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save.php',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        bla: navigator.appVersion,
        blah: navigator.platform
    }
});
```

Second problem is connected with first one:

How can I save more than one data:

```
<?php 
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
        $bla = $data['data1'];
        $blah = $data['data2'];

        $file = "test.txt"; 
        $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");

        fwrite($fh, $bla, $blah);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Comment: instead of foreach just use $_POST['bla']; and $_POST['blah'];

Comment: Hello if you can please post more enough from your code so we can detect where the problem persist because till now per example i don't have what you are posting as variable and what type of html element will carry out values and did you have many elemnt with same name or what ? if no so why this for each did you are trying to post a select element with multiple select options or what ?

Comment: Anyway i think that the first part of your problem solution's is found here :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15692090/1492486

and about the second part i am waiting you to post your form code that will carry out your data you want to post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_POST['bla'];` and `$_POST['blah'];` as your post variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) which serializes your objects/arrays.

```
var data = {
   object1: {version: navigator.appVersion},
   object2: {platform: navigator.platform},
   array1: ['one', 'two', 'three']
};
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save.php',
      cache: false,
      data: jQuery.param(data),
});
```

and you can see the data structure in php and parse acordingly:

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marhaba ! Assuming that you have just two input fields in your form you want post so what you need is just this type of code :

```
<?php
$tobewritten = "";
foreach($_POST as $data)
{
    $tobewritten.= $data . ",";
}
$tobewritten = substr($tobewritten,0,strlen($tobewritten)-1);

$file = "test.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh,$tobewritten);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Please 5alline a3ref if this code has helped you and has been the right solution for your problem :)