# How to send data to php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been searching around to find out how to do this but I can't find anything basic enough for my needs.

I want to create a 5 star rating system, that if the 3rd star is clicked for example it passes '3', '$variable1' and '$variable2' to 'rate.php'

I can then create a script in rate.php to insert a query into the correct table etc.

I can do this normally, but not using Ajax. How can I do it using ajax?

Comment: This has to be one of the most common questions on StackOverflow.  Have you really searched for a similar question already or are you fibbing?

Comment: Please post your code. If you don't have any, you haven't tried hard enough yet.

Comment: Look [THIS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/) or [THIS](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-rating-plugins/)

Comment: I've used the jQuery Raty plugin (http://wbotelhos.com/raty) before, it works well with Ajax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending data with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696509/sending-data-with-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "rate.php", 
            type: "post", //can be post or get
            data: {star: 3}, 
            success: function(){

            }
        });
```

In your rate.php you would do this depending on if you did a post or get

```
$variable1 = $_POST["star"]; //or $_GET["star"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't expect much more explanation than this without showing your code, what you've tried and what you've searched.

This shows the general format of how to do it. You will need to get your actual values into the code.

```
$.post('otherfile.php', {
    stars  : 3, 
    value1 : '$variable1', //whatever this is
    value2 : '$variable2'  //whatever this is
}, function(){
    alert('done');
});
```

On the PHP Side ...

```
echo $_POST['stars'];
echo $_POST['value1'];
echo $_POST['value2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You listen for an event on your stars, and when they are clicked, you get their value with `data()` and use `$.ajax()` to pass that value to your php file of choice. There you get it from the I/O stream or via POST / GET and do whatever...